# PHP connected on the html page, Click on button to shuffle

Tags: php, html, button, shuffle

For now, thirdChineseSentence.php, will shuffle only when i refresh the page. I would like to put for example: 'I play the piano' will appear on  thirdChineseSentence.html and only will shuffle when i click the scramble button. Please help:)

thirdChineseSentence.php

```
     <?php
     // Connect to database server
      mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

     // Select database
      mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

      // Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
      $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE id 
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";

      //create an array with numbers 1-4
      $order = array(1,2,3,4);

      //shuffle them in random order
      shuffle($order);

      $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

      // Loop the recordset $rs
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
     // Write the data of the person
     //Display all the array values from 0-3 (array index starts from 0)
     echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " . $row[$order[1]] . " " .                                                

     $row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";
    }
    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

thirdChineseSentence.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Sentence Scramble and Sequencer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Second.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">          
    </script>
     <script src="chinesesentence.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>


    <body>
<center>
    <img src = "http://imageshack.com/a/img842/1461/otd4.jpg"/>
     <h1>helloword</h1>
    <button id="showcontent">Scramble</button>
    <div id="content"></div>
    </center>

   </body>
    </html>
```

chinesesentence.js

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).on('click', '#showcontent', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.get("thirdChineseSentence.php", function(data) {
     $("div#content").html(data);
    });
    });

   });
```

Comment: **DO NOT** use `mysql` functions anymore. They have been depreciated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` functions instead.

Comment: 'Deprecated'. But also that does not answer the question. There are some reasons why people may continue to use `mysql` over `mysqli`. If a person asks a question although its advised to educate said person on deprecated code, its also a great idea to focus at their question. @DavidCorbin

Comment: Is there a shuffle function in your php?

Comment: All the files I have listed down:) I think the shuffle function should be place at the js file. But dont know how to implement it. So how can I shuffle the sentence only when i click the scramble button? @DavidCorbin

Comment: @user3678617 Check my answer. You will need to firstly load the sentence and change the js to what i wrote in the answer. That will make the button replace the div each time the button is pressed.

Comment: If you want to `shuffle()` in the client-side, then there is no reason to create a php array. You could have a JavaScript function that shuffles the numbers every time it is called by clicking a button.

Comment: You could also do what @StuartWickend did below and use an ajax request to shuffle. This way should be more 'random' since it is on the server side instead of the client side.

Comment: My php is for retrieve the data from my database. I have a problem also the my php file does not seem to be together with my html. The sentence appear on the web as a page and the html open up in other page, which the html page only have the button without the sentence. I would check if i really shuffle. May i know how to put them together. As my php file is to retieve the data from the database. @Stuart Wickenden

Comment: @DavidCorbin I have a problem too stated in the comment above.

Comment: If you want to put the HTML file in the PHP file, simply put the HTML code directly after the close of the PHP tag.

Comment: I have post my files below. Please help:)  @Stuart Wickenden @ David Corbin

Answer (score 0):

Replace your js with the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#showcontent').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        url = 'thirdChineseSentence.php';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url, 
                dataType: 'html',

                beforeSend: function() {
                        $( "#content" ).html( "Requesting.." );
                },
                success: function(html) {
                        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=html;
                }
            });

       });

   }
```

This will use `AJAX` and call the the `PHP` file each time the button is clicked, and then will replace the content in the div with the returned content from the `PHP` file.

Answer (score 0):

Like this right? but the sentence shuffle after i refresh the page each single time. When i click the scramble button there is no effect. @Stuart Wickenden  @ David Corbin

thirdChineseSentence.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Sentence Scramble and Sequencer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Second.css" />
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">       
   </script>
   <script src="chinesesentence.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
<center>
<img src = "http://imageshack.com/a/img842/1461/otd4.jpg"/>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>


  <?php
  // Connect to database server
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

  // Select database
  mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

  // Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
  $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE id 
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";

  //create an array with numbers 1-4
  $order = array(1,2,3,4);

  //shuffle them in random order
  shuffle($order);

  $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

  // Loop the recordset $rs
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  // Write the data of the person
  //Display all the array values from 0-3 (array index starts from 0)
  echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " . $row[$order[1]] . " " .  
 $row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";
  }
  // Close the database connection
  mysql_close();
  ?>

  <button id="showcontent">Scramble</button>
  <div id="content"></div>
 </center>

 </body>
 </html>
```

chinesesentence.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#showcontent').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    url = 'thirdChineseSentence.php';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url, 
            dataType: 'html',

            beforeSend: function() {
                    $( "#content" ).html( "Requesting.." );
            },
            success: function(html) {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=html;
            }
        });

        });

      }
```